# NIC handling multiple packets at once

Tags: multithreading, networking, parallelism

Can NIC handle(send/receive) multiple packets at once?
For example, 2 asynchronous tasks request 2 different things from a database. Are those 2 requests sent simultaneously by NIC? Also, are the responses interpreted simultaneously by NIC?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends what you mean by "simultaneously". At ground level, nothing is simultaneous. You can only send out one packet on the wire at once. You can only transfer one packet over the PCIe bus at once.

This is not something tasks in user space need to worry about.